# I am making a sign in page using bootstrap. How do I center it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I am doing a school project and I need to make a sign in page. I have found this code, but it is not showing up in the center of the page. It is showing up on the left side of the page. Well, the first part is showing up on the left side and the second part is showing up on the right side. I need the right side below the left side after it is centered. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- left half of the page -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="login.php">

                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value="" required autofocus>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- right half of the page -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h3>Not a member yet?</h3>
            <a href="join.php">Join our club</a>, it's the best!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I add more code? Why is it showing up on the left side of my screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class part of the div element you want to center, write "centered".

For example, if you want to center the row, change

```
<div class="row">
```

to

```
<div class="row centered">
```

This is usually a preset style class in Bootstrap. If this doesn't work, you can also use a style setting:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center">
```

Comment: I added an alternative way above

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
<center>[code]</center>
```

Also `<div class="centered">` is fine.